# Why I can't pass the address of the chain? Strtol

Tags: c

I have this code, the function strtol receives a double pointer, and it is assumed that the string "prueba" is a pointer that points to the memory address of the first element of the string (Which is the same memory address of the entire chain), Then it is as if it were passing the dir of a pointer, I do not know if I explain, anyway it does not work: / gives a warning  here

```
ret = strtol(str, &prueba, 10);
```

> long int strtol(const char *str, char **endptr, int base)
>
> strtol converts the initial part of the string in str to a long int
>   value according to the given base.
>       "endptr" his is the reference to an object of type char*, whose value is set by the function to the next character in str after the numerical value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str[30] = "2030300 This is test";
    char prueba[20];
    char *ptr;
    long ret;
    printf("\nLa cadena inicial es: %c%s%c\n",34,str,34);


    ret = strtol(str, &ptr, 10); 
    printf("\nThe number(unsigned long integer) is %ld\n", ret);
    printf("String part is |%s|\n", ptr); 

    ret = strtol(str, &prueba, 10);
    printf("\nProbando: %c%s%c\n",34,prueba,34);

   return(0);
```

Comment: `&prueba` is a pointer to an array of 20 `char`s.

Comment: `&prueba` is not a `char **`. It is a `char (*)[20]`. That is, it is a pointer to an array. You need to declare as: `char *prueba;`

Comment: but if i declare char *prueba it is a pointer to an array. like char prueba[20]

Comment: You would never want to pass an array, or a pointer to an array, as the second argument to `strtol`.  It only makes sense to pass the address of a pointer.  The purpose of the second argument of `strtol` is so that it can "return" a pointer to the spot where it stopped converting the integer.  It "returns" a pointer which points into your original string (in your case, `str`). That is, after you call `strtol(str, &ptr, 10)`, your pointer `ptr` is the returned pointer value, and it points somewhere within `str`.  What would you expect to happen if you passed the array `prueba` instead?

Comment: @EmiliOrtega No. `char *` is not an array. Even though sometimes they behave similarly.

Comment: @SteveSummit You should make that an answer. If you'd like, I can instead; I certainly wouldn't mind stealing the rep from you ;)

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I don't remember why I didn't make it an answer, but if you'd like to, be my guest, and use the rep in good health! :-)

Comment: @SteveSummit I posted an answer. It.. doesn't actually reference your comment at all, but it says a lot of the same things. Could you take a look when you get a chance and tell me what I messed up? :)

Answer (score 3):

I see one big misconception here that needs to be addressed: **Pointers are not the same as arrays**. A pointer is a thing which tells you how to find something else; that something else could be a single thing, or enough uninitialized space to hold a thing, or a bunch of them in a block. An array is a block of things, and very specifically *not* a pointer to a block of things. That you can put `[0]` after each and end up with a thing is irrelevant to this discussion.

Why does't it decay into a `char *` that represents the address of its first element, like it would if passed to a function or even assigned? Because the C standard says it won't -- it defines precisely three exceptions to the "arrays decay into pointers to their first element" rule. One of them is when that array is the operand of the `&` operator, so that you get a pointer to the thing you're asking about, and not something else which, though related, isn't that thing.

Because of that, you're not passing a `char **` into `strtol`. You're passing a pointer to an array. While that might be OK in some cases, it's not here, since the function wants to put a `char *` where you're telling it to put one; if you try to say "put it in this `char[]`", it's not going to do what you want. It'll try to stuff a `char *` into your `char[]`, and you'll get undefined behavior.

For further reading, see comp.lang.c FAQ questions [6.2](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html) and [6.3](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html).

---

Oh, and by the way, GCC will warn you about this if you tell it to: Pass `-Wincompatible-pointer-types` or, better yet, something like `-Wall -Werror` (depending on your compiler's recommendation), to the compiler -- it'll produce a warning that looks roughly like this:

```
/path/to/main.c: In function 'main':
/path/to/main.c:17:23: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strtol' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     ret = strtol(str, &prueba, 10);
                       ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:29:0,
                 from /path/to/main.c:1:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:166:6: note: expected 'char ** restrict' but argument is of type 'char (*)[20]'
 long _EXFUN(strtol,(const char *__restrict __n, char **__restrict __end_PTR, int __base));
```

The exact text may differ, of course, but the gist of it will be the same.

Comment: As you "asked" for it: You cannot apply the index-operator (resp, + or -) to an array. It just **looks** as-if (sounds like nit-picking, but once you understand this, you understand arrays in C). And the reason it does not work (apart from the problem with the type) is simply because you cannot change the value of the array itself (the array has no value on its own like a pointer has, it's just the elements). Finally: The C info-page lists recommended warnings. These include `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion`. Personally, I'd recommend a whole bunch more.

Comment: `long _EXFUN( ...` ?? Huh, never seen such a message.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah, I was a little less strictly correct (i.e. I was speaking from a syntax POV -- `int a[2]; a[0];` is valid syntax, as is `int *a; a[0];`. I think that similarity is the cause of the confusion, but I'll make that explicit. WRT to why it doesn't work -- whoops, yeah, I should definitely make that explicit. That's what I was getting at with "putting it in this `char[]`", but it... didn't really get across. WRT `long _EXFUN` -- that's literally what my compiler outputted when I compiled the code. I don't know where it came from.

Comment: From the paths, I assume linux/unix, thus gcc or clang, resp. glibc (or is it BSD?). But I might be wrong and it is mingw or cygwin and that's some Windows thingie? I just can't remember to have seen such a codeline on Linux, but otoh, I normally don't use the stdlib or get many diagnostics for my code anyway.

Comment: @Olaf It's GCC/Cygwin. To be honest, I'm not sure it matters; I'll edit my answer to make it more clear that the warning produced is an example.

Comment: I don't think it matters, either. Was just curious. So it is most likely the Windows libc or Windows-specific part of the glibc (possibly to call the Windows-libc functions).